# How can I use graphframes with pyspark on AWS EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr, graphframes

I'm trying to use the [graphframes](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes) package in pyspark in Jupyter Notebook (using Sagemaker and sparkmagic) on AWS EMR.  I've tried adding a configuration option when creating the EMR cluster in the AWS console:

```
[{"classification":"spark-defaults", "properties":{"spark.jars.packages":"graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11"}, "configurations":[]}]
```

But I still got an error when trying to use the graphframes package in my pyspark code in jupyter notebook.

Here's my code (it's from the graphframes example):

```
# Create a Vertex DataFrame with unique ID column "id"
v = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
], ["id", "name", "age"])
# Create an Edge DataFrame with "src" and "dst" columns
e = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "b", "friend"),
  ("b", "c", "follow"),
  ("c", "b", "follow"),
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])
# Create a GraphFrame
from graphframes import *
g = GraphFrame(v, e)

# Query: Get in-degree of each vertex.
g.inDegrees.show()

# Query: Count the number of "follow" connections in the graph.
g.edges.filter("relationship = 'follow'").count()

# Run PageRank algorithm, and show results.
results = g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.01, maxIter=20)
results.vertices.select("id", "pagerank").show()
```

And here's the output/error:

```
ImportError: No module named graphframes
```

I read through [this git thread](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/172) but all the potential work-arounds seem very complicated and require ssh-ing into the master node of the EMR cluster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured out that there is a [PyPi package for graphframes](https://pypi.org/project/graphframes/).  I used this to create a bootstrapping action as detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-install-kernels-libs.html), although I changed things a little bit.

Here's what I did to get graphframes working on EMR:

1. First I created a shell script and saved it so s3 named "install_jupyter_libraries_emr.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo pip install graphframes
```

2. I then went through the advanced options EMR creation process in the AWS console.

   - During Step 1, I added in the maven coordinates of the graphframes package within the edit software settings text box:

   ```
   [{"classification":"spark-defaults","properties":{"spark.jars.packages":"graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11"}}]
   ```

   - During Step 3: General Cluster Settings, I went into the bootstrap actions section
   - Within the bootstrap actions section, I added a new custom boostrap action with:

     - an arbitrary name
     - The s3 location of my "install_jupyter_libraries_emr.sh" script
     - no optional arguments
   - I then started the cluster creation
3. Once my cluster was up, I got into Jupyter and ran my code:

```
# Create a Vertex DataFrame with unique ID column "id"
v = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
], ["id", "name", "age"])
# Create an Edge DataFrame with "src" and "dst" columns
e = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "b", "friend"),
  ("b", "c", "follow"),
  ("c", "b", "follow"),
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])
# Create a GraphFrame
from graphframes import *
g = GraphFrame(v, e)

# Query: Get in-degree of each vertex.
g.inDegrees.show()

# Query: Count the number of "follow" connections in the graph.
g.edges.filter("relationship = 'follow'").count()

# Run PageRank algorithm, and show results.
results = g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.01, maxIter=20)
results.vertices.select("id", "pagerank").show()
```

And this time, finally, I got the correct output:

```
+---+--------+
| id|inDegree|
+---+--------+
|  c|       1|
|  b|       2|
+---+--------+

+---+------------------+
| id|          pagerank|
+---+------------------+
|  b|1.0905890109440908|
|  a|              0.01|
|  c|1.8994109890559092|
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: wonderful answer, i appreciate that you  came back with your solution. If it were up to me I would give you all the fake internet points. Thanks so much

Comment: With the latest AWS EMR cluster I had to use

"sudo pip-3.6 install graphframes"

to make it work (instead of simply pip)

Comment: Is STEP 1 really needed? The [graphframes documentation](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/quick-start.html) says "We use the --packages argument to download the graphframes package and any dependencies automatically."

Comment: @panc It may not be needed any more, I haven't tested.  At the time, if I just did the spark package, but not the pip install, when I would try to import graphframes in jupyter notebook, I would get an error that it couldn't find the graphframes package.

Answer (score 7):

@Bob Swain's answer is fine, but now the repositories for graphframes are located at https://repos.spark-packages.org/. Thus, in order to make it work the classification should be changed to:

```
[
 {
  "classification":"spark-defaults",
  "properties":{
    "spark.jars.packages":"graphframes:graphframes:0.8.0-spark2.4-s_2.11",
    "spark.jars.repositories":"https://repos.spark-packages.org/"
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: I am using sagemaker's sparkmagic kernel (pyspark) and EMR with Livy to run pyspark code. By adding those two configuration in Sparkmagic's `%%config`, I can successfully run pyspark graphframes examples.

Comment: @panc Could you please share more details of your solution

Comment: @Shweta I have a setup with Sagemaker instance backed by EMR, similar to that created by following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-backed-by-spark-in-amazon-emr/). Then, in the jupyter notebook, I use sparkmagic's pyspark kernel, [this](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/examples/Pyspark%20Kernel.ipynb) is an example. Additional configuration examples can be found in [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-studio-magics.html).

Answer (score 0):

My requirement: To Map the property graph model in Hadoop (AWS EMR) and store it somewhere so we can query later.

Is there any option to get the result in as a graph also?
I have read few documents on Graphx which is a library supported by APache spark , I don't have clear idea